# Changing blocks based on visitor's country

Tags: 6, blocks

On a Drupal 6 site I am trying to display blocks on my site based on user's country.

1. To do this I had to install  'IP to Country' module
2. Updated IP to Country
3. Created a new block and added the following code into the block body to print the user's country code:

   ```
   <?php
   $co=module_invoke('ip2cc','get_country',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];);
   print($co->country_code);
   ?>
   ```
4. Then, under 'Show block on specific pages' selected 'Show if the following PHP code returns TRUE (PHP-mode, experts only).' and then added the below mentioned code, so that the block is displayed based on the country ID.

   ```
   <?php $co->country_code == "IN" ?>
   ```

After doing all these the block is getting disabled for the ID mentioned, eg: If 'IN' is mentioned the block should only be displayed for Indian visitors, but the block is actually being disabled.

Comment: did u load ip database?

Comment: Yes I did load the IP database, and confirmed by downloading the 'ip-to-country.csv' file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be right. You've mis-spelled the module name in the `module_invoke` function at #3 and misplaced the semicolon `;`

Try this:

```
<?php

$detectedcountry = module_invoke('ip2country','get_country',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$us_canada = array(
  'US','CA'
);

//return true in block visibility when the country appears to be in detected country
if(in_array($detectedcountry,$us_canada)){
  return true;
} 

?>
```

Comment: I tried above mentioned code, but it is not working for me for 'IN' country code.

Comment: @AnAnD try to `print` the value of the `$detectedcountry` array in your custom module, using some `hook` (`hook_init` would help); and check to see it the countries are actually being loaded. Except that I don't think there might be a problem here.

Comment: btw, I am using http://drupal.org/project/ip2cc module and the module name is ip2cc

Comment: I am able to print the country code using the code that I have mentioned above.

Comment: @AnAnD : We both are completely on different pages :P
My solution would be applicable for http://drupal.org/project/ip2country and not for ip2cc

Comment: @AnAnD : IN the problem statement, you didn't return `TRUE` when the code is `IN`, that should be the reason of it not working.

Comment: I am sorry, I am installing the 'ip2country' module now

Comment: No need to say sorry ;-) Just put `return TRUE;` in your code at #4 after `if($co->country_code == 'IN')`.

Comment: I tried, but no luck, below is the code:
`<?php`
`$co=module_invoke('ip2cc','get_country',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);`
`print($co->country_code);`

`if($co->country_code == 'IN'){`
`return true;`
`}`

`?>`